# Attempt to update one mySQL table with data from two other tables is failing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to update one table which holds the inputted data from my employees. The table has three columns: entry id, field id, and value. I am wanting to make sure there is a row for every field in the this table according to each entry. As such I have the written the following php/sql script. The thought process was get two arrays (one containing the entry ids and the other the field ids) and check the input table to see if there was an existing row for every field and entry. If not then use an inert into command to add a row with the value 0, but this command is failing. My guess is a timeout error due to the intensity of this function. Any suggestions?

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$field_query = 'SELECT id FROM `jos_directory_field`';
$db->setQuery( $field_query );
$fields = $db->loadObjectList();

$entry_query = 'SELECT id FROM `jos_directory_entry`';
$db->setQuery( $entry_query );
$entries = $db->loadObjectList();

  for($e=0;$e count($entries);$e++) {
    for($i=0;$i count($fields);$i++) {
      $insert_query = 'INSERT INTO `jos_directory_enf` (entry_id,field_id,field_value)';
      $insert_query .= 'SELECT '.$entries[$e]->id.','.$fields[$i]->id.',0';
      $insert_query .= 'FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `jos_directory_enf`';
      $insert_query .= 'WHERE entry_id = '.$entries[$e]->id.' and field_id = '.$fields[$i]->id.')';
      $db->setQuery( $insert_query );
      $db->query();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this bomb out immediately, or appear to hang?

Comment: And how big are the tables - you could be getting out-of-memory from PHP itself, simply because of your table size (mmm, maybe somewhat unlikely).  Also, what `COMMIT` level are you running under?

Comment: Do you have an actual table called DUAL?   Or is this a carry-over from ORACLE syntax?

Comment: @MarcB It ran for about 30 to 60 seconds before bringing an internal server error.

Comment: @X-Zero My assumption of the problem is a timeout via PHP. I do not know what the COMMIT level is.

Comment: @Sparky I assume it is carry over syntax. I copied it from a function I wrote a while ago.

Comment: This morning I checked the sql table and my above function did work, but only until it timed out. If anyone knows a sql function that will accomplish my need without duplicating existing entries, I would be greatly obliged!

Answer (score 0):

It's too bad Joomla doesn't appear to support prepared statements, as they can help with performance for repeated queries.

However, in this case there's a better option. You should be able to replace the PHP code with a single SQL statement, making use of the `IGNORE` clause for [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) statements. First, make sure you have a [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html) on the `entry_id` and `field_id` columns of `jos_directory_enf`. Then the SQL statement would be something like:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `jos_directory_enf` (entry_id,field_id,field_value)
  SELECT e.id, f.id, 0
  FROM jos_directory_entries AS e
    JOIN jos_directory_field AS f
;
```

.

Comment: I assumed INSERT IGNORE would duplicate rows, but I decided to run it anyways with your suggestion. It does indeed duplicate every existing row as well as add the needed.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't create the unique index, as I mention. If you do, duplicate rows will cause a duplicate-key error, preventing the rows from being added. The `IGNORE` will prevent the error from stopping the query.